# Mysql Simple update procedure

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL database and I'm having a tough time figuring out the mistake in the below update query

```
create procedure plu_update_stock
(in p_item_number varchar , in p_amount_sold decimal)
beginupdate WaspTrackInventory.dbo.item
    set qty_available = qty_available - p_amount_sold
where item_number = p_item_number
    ;
end
```

I get this error

```
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure plu_update_stock, Line 3
```

Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'in'.

Can someone help me figure out the mistake

Comment: The error `Msg 156, Level 15...` implies this is _not_ MySQL you're using, but rather MS SQL Server.  MySQL's error message would be something like `Error 1064. Please check the manual for the correct syntax to use near...`

Comment: `beginupdate` looks bogus to me

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-procedure.html

Comment: Try adding a space after `begin`.

Comment: Thanks tom! I think I will start again with the link you gave me! I never thought I would say this .... But I will be glade to get back to an oracle database.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE plu_update_stock (IN p_item_number VARCHAR, IN p_amount_sold DECIMAL)
BEGIN
    UPDATE `WaspTrackInventory.dbo.item`
        SET qty_available = qty_available - p_amount_sold
            WHERE item_number = p_item_number;
END;
```

but i believe, the name `p_item_number` looks like `INT`, because it is the "number", and the table with name `WaspTrackInventory.dbo.item` with dots looks unusual for me.

Comment: I check the database that column type its definitely a p_item_number.

The dots are just denoting the path to the table. Unfortunately I have tried it with and without and no dice. Thanks though

Comment: No 'as' was in my code and the IN's were the wrong syntax for the database.... I should have put @ in front of it